# Vue.js meta Router not rendering the component

Tags: vue.js

I followed this tutorial on adding meta in a router for multiple layouts
it works but the component inside the layout not working

[Dynamic Layouts](https://dev.to/lampewebdev/vuejs-pages-with-dynamic-layouts-problems-and-a-solution-4460)

// update // in DevTools, I don't see the components anywhere just the layouts
here's my code

App.vue

```
  <div id="app">
    <component :is="this.$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
      <router-view />
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

  
<script>
export default {
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

router/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import weappLayout from '../layouts/webappLayout.vue'
import noLayout from '../layouts/no-layout.vue'
import signIN from '../views/sign-in.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: { layout: weappLayout }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'sign-in',
    component: signIN,
    meta: { layout: noLayout }
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

if the components is needed to look at let me know, thank you in advance <3

sign-in.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form class="form-signin">
      <img
        class="mb-4"
        src=""
        alt=""
        width="72"
        height="72"
      />
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        id="inputEmail"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Email address"
        required
        autofocus
      />
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        id="inputPassword"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Password"
        required
      />
      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" /> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Sign in
      </button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2020</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "sign-in"
};
</script>

<style  >
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

</style>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src



export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {

  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: **Never** use `this` inside template - `<component :is="this.$route.meta.layout || 'div'">` should be `<component :is="$route.meta.layout || 'div'">`

Comment: I did remove ```this``` and still the same problem

Comment: Well "not working" is not a "problem" anyone here can solve. Use your browser Dev Tools, watch console for errors, update your question with more info...

Comment: Okay thanks for the clearance

Comment: Where did you register the layout component? I can't see it in the code you shared.

Comment: I Added them just now

Answer (score 1):

/// SOLVED Finally //
it was to add `slot` tag in the layout template
thanks,